# How to pass values between xpages in different notes databases?

Tags: xpages

My xpage have a simple 'status' field and a xp:link in A database. The xp:link have a script action to redirect to B database:

```
 <xp:eventHandler event='onclick' submit='true' refreshMode='complete'>
    <xp:this.action><xp:executeScript>
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect('http://domino/databaseB.nsf/testLink.xsp');
}]]></xp:this.script></xp:executeScript>
    </xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler>
```

How can I pass the 'status' value to testLink.xsp in B database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best and easiest way would be to adding a query parameter like "testLink.xsp?status=xxx".

Of course in this case you would be revealing the information sent in the url. If it's not desirable (you don't want the user o see the value you have transferred), you can design an intermediatte page (e.g. an XAgent) in database B. You send two parameters to this page;

/dbB.nsf/redirect.xsp?status=XXX&redirectTo=testLink.xsp

Then you add this value to the sessionScope at the redirect.xsp and redirect the user to the other page.

Comment: Intermediate page still is "revealing the information sent in the url". One could just forge intermediate page's url. So, it might be considered as overengineering.

Answer (score 4):

Another option, a bit more complicated, but "hidden": In [Nathan's XSP Starter kit](http://www.openntf.org/p/XSP%20Starter%20Kit) there is a template for a "server scope" scope implementation. If you add isolation code there (e.g. a List with entries per user) you can easily pass values between applications. You would want to add a session listener to clear a user's variable once the session expires.

Last: you could keep the application (your xsp) in a single database and just point your data source to the other database.

Comment: I agree with Stephan's second option and that's what I tend to do, since it's easier to keep all the xpages in a single database and refer to external data sources.